# How to check image (dynamic generated) hosting on my server loaded by what URL?

Tags: html, ruby, image, webserver

My server generated a dynamic image (`http://myserver.com/image/71286cdef.png`) and laded by other sites. This html is embedded to a page in other server (say http://www.othersite.com/787878.html)

```
<img src='http://myserver.com/image/71286cdef.png'/>
```

How do I detect this url (`http://www.othersite.com/787878.html`) loading image in my server

```
http://myserver.com/image/71286cdef.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Non Ruby specific: Normally browsers send ["referer"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) header along with all requests to resources on original page. So in code that generates the image you can check that header.

You can also configure your server to log referrer header along with other standard properties (IP, Url, query parameter) if you need it just for analysis later.

Note: this header can be missing or forged - there is no really reliable way to confirm who requested the image. (Maybe short of SSL with client certificate).

Possible Ruby code from [Dealing With Ruby Vulnerabilities: Check HTTP Referrers](http://ruby.about.com/od/security/a/httpreferers.htm)

```
 if (
   ( request.headers['referer'].nil? ) or
   ( (request.headers['referer'] =~ %r[^http://#{request.host_with_port}/]).nil? )
   )
   flash[:notice] = "Incorrect Referer header"
   redirect_to :action => 'index'
 end
```